# Observable list is not populated when refreshing the page

Tags: angular, observable

Following this thread:
[InvalidPipeArgument: '' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50784588/invalidpipeargument-for-pipe-asyncpipe)

I'm trying to understand why the Observable list is not populated/reflected on the screen when refreshing the page with Refresh button of the browser.
When using a Refresh button form control and calling the same code it works.

Is it because Observable array is being filled on going and not at once? Meanwhile the html loops over the list while it's empty?

When I print to console the response I can see that the array does contain actual result (but still not shown on the screen):

```
callGetResources() {
    if (this.route.outlet === Constants.APP_USER) {
        // When refreshing the page, user is still not populated
        this.resourcesService.getUser()
        .subscribe( data => {
            this.resources = this.resourcesService.getResources(data.text());
//this.resourcesService.getResources(data.text()).subscribe( response => {
//console.log(response);//});
        });
```

One more thing, I'm using different tabs with different outlets if it makes a different!

```
constructor(private service: ResourcesService, private router: Router) {

    this.router.navigate([{ outlets: {  ['appUser'] : ['resources-list'] } }]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `this.resourcesService.getResources(data.text())` returns a observable as i can see. If you wanna display data from this observable use `async` pipe in the template or save data from observable in the local variable and display this variable in the template (sorry for my English)
Also you can use mergeMap instead of nested subscribe.

```
callGetResources() {
  if (this.route.outlet === Constants.APP_USER) {
    this.resources = this.resourcesService.getUser()
       .pipe(
          mergeMap(data => this.resourcesService.getResources(data.text())
       )
```

and in template use `resources | async`

or use local variable

```
callGetResources() {
  if (this.route.outlet === Constants.APP_USER) {
    this.resourcesService.getUser()
       .pipe(
          mergeMap(data => this.resourcesService.getResources(data.text())
       )
       .subscribe(resources => this.resources = resources);
```

Comment: when you refresh page you refresh all app and you need get data from the server again

Comment: Thanks man, you saved me a lot of time.
The mergeMap did the difference!!! Still don't understand how it's different from nested subscription, but it works.